# How to manage collision of two player ?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I'm developing a multi-player car game. 
Suppose that car A hit car B: both A and B have Rigidbody and collision functions attached. 
Because car A hit car B i want to take actions only to car A (add or remove point) but not to B. 
So i need to identify that car A is 'hit' (with guilty ) car B that has no 'guilty'. 
Can you suggest me how to do ?

Comment: You probably need to do a bit of math to see which car is facing towards the other. Or you could raytrace from the front of the cars? Assuming that the 'guilty' car is the one that drives it's front into the other car.

Comment: How do you determine the "guilty" party in a car crash? I guess that's more of a question for https://law.stackexchange.com :). No, seriously, when two cars collide, what exacly is your technical definition of "guilty" and "non-guilty"? When two cars drive behind each other, the front car breaks and the one behind crashes into the back of the car in front, who is "guilty"? The front car or the back car? And what about a frontal crash where both cars behave exactly identical?

Comment: Philipp you're right. In my 'head' i was thinking a car A that crash into B from back. When both collide from 'front' there's equal 'guilty'.

Comment: @stighy So your definition is "the one who crashes more frontal is the guilty one?